# How to loop through list and assign some variables as a key and some as a value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hellooo,

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to loop through a list and assign some as keys and some as values. I've searched through Stack Overflow for awhile now and couldn't find a question quite like this so I'm posting.

Here's the situation:

```
my_list = ['start_here', 'a1', 'b2', 'a3', 'start_here_2', 'b1', 'a2', 'start_here_3', 'a1', 'b2', 'a3', 'b4']
```

(and it could continue to start_here_4, start_here_5, etc with any number of a# or b#s)

And here's my desired output:

```
my_dict = {'start_here': ['a1', 'b2', 'a3'], 'start_here_2': ['b1', 'a2'], 'start_here_3': ['a1', 'b2', 'a3', 'b4']
```

I don't know if I should split my original list into 3 or 4 or however many and then make index 0 the key, followed by a list of the variables remaining as the value or if there's a way to bypass that and create a dictionary from the original list immediately.

Thank you in advance, I'm a bit new!

Comment: You'll likely have to loop to identify what is a key and what is a value and which values are associated to each key to build our your dictionary.

Comment: *"[...] or if there's a way to bypass that and create a dictionary from the original list immediately"* - well, do you own the code that creates the original list?  It is much easier to keep your data in a sensible format from the beginning, rather than trying to translate a bad format later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```py
my_list = ['start_here', 'a1', 'b2', 'a3', 'start_here_2', 'b1', 'a2', 'start_here_3', 'a1', 'b2', 'a3', 'b4']
key = None
my_dict = {}
for v in my_list:
    if v.find('start_here') == 0:
        key = v
        my_dict[key] = []
    else:
        my_dict[key].append(v)
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'start_here': ['a1', 'b2', 'a3'], 'start_here_2': ['b1', 'a2'], 'start_here_3': ['a1', 'b2', 'a3', 'b4']}
```

The `find` method identifies each list element beginning with `start_here`, saves that element as the new key and adds an entry to `my_dict` with that key and with an empty list as the value, then appends subsequent list elements to that key's list value until the next key (namely, the next list element beginning with `start_here`) is encountered.

**UPDATE**: Alternatives to using `find()` (probably superior) are shown below.

(1) Assuming any string in the list beginning with `start_here` is to be treated as a key (credit to @Jasmijn in a comment):

```py
key = None
my_dict = {}
for v in my_list:
    if v.startswith('start_here'):
        key = v
        my_dict[key] = []
    else:
        my_dict[key].append(v)
```

(2) Assuming any string in the list containing `start_here` as a substring is to be treated as a key:

```
key = None
my_dict = {}
for v in my_list:
    if 'start_here' in v:
        key = v
        my_dict[key] = []
    else:
        my_dict[key].append(v)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much and thank you for the explanation! Your code previously had != -1 instead of == 0, can you explain the difference btwn the two?

Comment: If we use `!= -1`, it will match any string containing `start_here`, not just strings *beginning* with `start_here` which is what `== 0` tests for. Docs for `str` are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) (search for "find(").

Comment: Instead of `v.find('start_here') == 0`, it's better to use `v.startswith('start_here')`

Comment: @Jasmijn That's probably true, and even if any string containing `start_here` should be considered a key, the better way according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) is to use `'start_here' in v` rather than `find()`.